# Android: Less broad app-visibility method should be used

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, android-manifest

After publishing in the play store they reviewed our app they sent this message to my mail.

[image: Response from google play console]

Following is the manifest file.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="se.thelins"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="mailto" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

    <application
        android:label="Thelins"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCFsgpO9RT68LqCGHQ1rzyaf2zrxrUMRS0"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
                android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="thelins" android:host="swish" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.apptreesoftware.barcodescan.BarcodeScannerActivity"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I can't find much about this issue over the internet, If you need any further information please ask in the comments section.

Comment: Have you found any solution for this? My app also rejected.

Comment: Yes, in my case the problem was that under inter testing I had uploaded an old APK which had QUERY_ALL_PACKEGS permission so I had to replace that as well.

After doing that my App went live.

Let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: Great I did same..

Comment: I hope the issue is resolved now.